# How can an android crash backtrace happen with stack frames on the heap?

Tags: c++, c, crash

For example if an android crash says that the backtrace was:

```
backtrace:
#00 pc 0000000003709330  [anon:libc_malloc]
    at [anon:libc_malloc].0x3709330(Native Method)
```

What I understand is that it was attempting to execute code that is stored on the heap.

In a C or C++ program, are there language features that would typically do that or does this more likely indicate some kind of corruption?

Comment: A little context (_i.e._ your own code from further up the stack) would help. If you're crashing in `malloc` then you probably have heap corruption which is typically caused by your program doing crazy stuff. If you have no other stack frames, you probably have stack corruption and/or heap corruption.

Comment: In this case, there are no more stack frames.

From what I understand, it's not crashing in malloc but rather it's trying to execute code on the heap (and android has labeled the memory with [anon:libc_malloc] to tell us the memory came from malloc)

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, you'll need to step through with a debugger. If it really is executing this, then you might have broken your stack in some fundamental way that results in a jump instruction into that function on return from another. Seems far-fetched. General memory corruption is my suspicion, and it can behave in weird ways. This seems more more plausible than the idea of something arbitrarily executing code. Again, more context is required. What is the execption code? Can you reproduce it? Can you debug it?

Comment: It should be noted that when you crash, the address (and any function that it resolves to) points to the place where the unhandled exception or fatal error occurred. So in this case it looks like `malloc` crashed. Now, that can happen if you have completely broken the heap. If no other frames are available, it can be because the stack was wiped out by the same issue or as a side-effect. Your program may have even continued "normally" for a while since the initial event that eventually resulted in a crash. Try adding explicit heap checks in strategic places to help isolate/identify the problem.